# String formatting and condition operator

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I'm trying to use a format a string inside a condition operator. But the colon in `:X2` is interpreted as the condition-separator and not to string-formatter symbol.

Is there a way to do this in one line?

```
return $"#{(includeAlpha ? color.A:X2 : "")}{color.R:X2}{color.G:X2}{color.B:X2}";
```

(Of course it works with an if-else statement but I'm trying to do it in one line. Brackets didn't work)

Comment: color.A.ToString("X2")